# AppleTv / TvOS - Resize TopShelf Images in TVContentItems Saved to ImageURL

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I am implementing TopShelf in Apple tvOS. I have downloaded images and assigned to **imageURL** of **TVContentItems**. The downloaded images aspect ratio does not fit into the TopShelf Images properly. I have tried to change the size by appending width + height to the image link.

www.mydownloadedimages.com/{width}x{height}

But it didn't work.

Can I do resizing at client end in any other way. In the TVContentItem class I have only have NSURL object. There is no UIImage Object.

Thanks a lot.

Here is Apple's documentation on Image Sizes and shapes

```
// ~ 2 : 3
// ~ 1 : 1
// ~ 4 : 3
// ~ 16 : 9
// ~ 8 : 3
// ~ 87 : 28


 //@property imageShape
 //@abstract A TVContentItemImageShape value describing the intended aspect ratio or shape of the image.
 //@discussion  For Top Shelf purposes: the subset of values which are //valid in this property, for TVContentItems in the topShelfItems property //of the TVTopShelfProvider, depends on the value of the topShelfStyle //property of the TVTopShelfProvider:


                    TVTopShelfContentStyleInset:

                        valid: TVContentItemImageShapeExtraWide

                    TVTopShelfContentStyleSectioned:

                        valid: TVContentItemImageShapePoster

                        valid: TVContentItemImageShapeSquare

                        valid: TVContentItemImageShapeHDTV
```

*When the value of this property is not valid for the Top Shelf style, the system reserves the right to scale the image in any way.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right saying that the `TVContentItem` has no `UIImage` type property. Since `TVContentItem` also accepts local file URLs in the `imageURL` property, a workaround can be:

- grabbing the `UIImage` from internet
- creating a new image context with the size of the top shelf image
- saving it into the `NSCacheDirectory`
- setting the local image URL as `imageURL`.

Here are the steps:

1. Let's create our `TVContentItem` object:

   ```
   let identifier = TVContentIdentifier(identifier: "myPicture", container: wrapperID)!
   let contentItem = TVContentItem(contentIdentifier: identifier )!
   ```
2. Set the `contentItem`'s `imageShape`:

   ```
   contentItem.imageShape = .HDTV
   ```
3. Grab the image from Internet. Actually I did this synchronously, you can also try to use other async methods to get that (`NSURLConnection`, AFNetworking, etc...):

   ```
   let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://s3-ak.buzzfed.com/static/2014-07/16/9/enhanced/webdr08/edit-14118-1405517808-7.jpg")!)!
   ```
4. Prepare the path where your image will be saved and get your `UIImage` from the `data` object:

   ```
   let filename = "picture-test.jpg"
   let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
   let filepath = paths.first! + "/" + filename
   let img : UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!
   ```
5. Assuming you've already set the `topShelfStyle` property, get the size of the top shelf image with the method `TVTopShelfImageSizeForShape`. This will be the size of your image context:

   ```
   let shapeSize : CGSize = TVTopShelfImageSizeForShape(contentItem.imageShape, self.topShelfStyle)
   ```
6. Create your image context of `shapeSize` size and draw the downloaded image into the context rect. Here you can do all your modifications to the image to adjust it into the desired size. In this example I took a square image from Instagram and I put white letterbox bands on the right and left sides.

   ```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(shapeSize)
   let imageShapeInRect : CGRect = CGRectMake((shapeSize.width-shapeSize.height)/2,0,shapeSize.height,shapeSize.height)
   img.drawInRect(imageShapeInRect)
   let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
   ```
7. In the end, save this image into your `NSCacheDirectory` and set the image path as `contentItem`'s `imageURL`.

   ```
   UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8)!.writeToFile(filepath, atomically: true)
   contentItem.imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
   ```
8. Complete your `TVContentItem` with other details (like title, internal link, etc...), run the top shelf extension... et voilà!
   [image: tvOS Screenshot]

Comment: I tried something similar as suggested by Niccola. I ran into the problem, that the topshelf process gets killed, when preparing the topshelf items takes too long. So I moved the creation of the images to my App, as the images do not change that often. From the topshelf I then dereference the created image files. This requires, that the app has to be started once before the topshelf can show images. ANother problem is, that topshelf images are cached. Even when the images are rewritten by the app, the images shown in the topshelf do not update. So be careful with this.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to Nicola Giancecchi's answer.  The Top Shelf extension will run on a non main thread so using methods like `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` will sometimes stop the Top Shelf thread printing this in the console:

> Program ended with exit code: 0

To fix this you can wrap your code like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8)!.writeToFile(filepath, atomically: true)

    let imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
    if #available(tvOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *) {
        contentItem.setImageURL(imageURL, forTraits: .userInterfaceStyleLight)
        contentItem.setImageURL(imageURL, forTraits: .userInterfaceStyleDark)
    } else {
        contentItem.imageURL = imageURL
    }
}
```